# Has anyone ever been punished for Project MK-ULTRA?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, law, cia

So I've been looking into what [MK-ULTRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_MKUltra) is, and recently a scary question has came to mind. That question being, has anyone been punished for the events of MK-ULTRA? By punished, I don't mean a slap on the wrist or the loss of a job. I mean more on the sense of legal ramifications. If not, was there any real reason they weren't?

Comment: What is the basis for assuming someone would have been punished? Did anyone do anything illegal?

Comment: What are legal ramifications? What was illegal? Which laws were broken?  In general "loss of a job" is illegal unless it is supported by legal process.

Comment: There is a difference between legal and power. At the top there is power, not law.

Comment: @DVK Apparently, very illegal, mostly breaches of the Nuremberg Code (i.e. illegal human experimentation without the subjects' knowledge or consent) and also probably at least one murder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Wiki with references there:

> The program engaged in many illegal activities;[3][4][5] in particular
> it used unwitting U.S. and Canadian citizens as its test subjects,
> which led to controversy regarding its legitimacy.[3]

Some of the methods:

> administration of drugs (especially LSD) and other chemicals,
> hypnosis, sensory deprivation, isolation, verbal and sexual abuse, as
> well as various forms of torture.

No one was charged.

Comment: This answer is long on conjecture and short on facts.

Comment: @ihtkwot Some more facts https://www.intelligence.senate.gov/sites/default/files/hearings/95mkultra.pdf.e.g. It's ok, but we want oversight and control.

Comment: Anyone have a source for "No one was charged"?

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing I could find to any kind of restitution is mentioned in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_MKUltra):

> Although the government aggressively, and sometimes successfully,
> sought to avoid legal liability, several plaintiffs did receive
> compensation through court order, out-of-court settlement, or acts of
> Congress. Frank Olson's family received $750,000 by a special act of
> Congress, and both President Ford and CIA director William Colby met
> with Olson's family to apologize publicly.

Not all such lawsuits were successful, and I can find no evidence so far of any criminal charges being pursued.